# Dynamic pivot in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have table with columns as:

```
ProductID ProductName ProductCategory Storage
1         Doll        Toy             A1
2         Car         Toy             A2
3         Cola        Drink           A1
4         Pure Water  Drink           A3
```

I want the output table in this format:

```
Storage Toy Drink
A1      1   1
A2      1   0
A3      0   1
```

Please help me how should I resolve this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic sql query with `STUFF`.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select [Storage], ' 
                + stuff((select distinct  ', sum(case [ProductCategory] 
                when ''' + [ProductCategory] + ''' 
                then 1 else 0 end) as ' + [ProductCategory]
                from [your_table_table]
                for xml path('')
                ), 1, 2, '')
                +' from [your_table_table] group by [Storage]';

 exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. One more question: Can the output have percentage? (like A1 50% 50%, A2 50% 0%, A3 0% 50%)